# SSIS, компонент скрипт (C#), создание текстовых файлов

Tags: c#, ssis

Знакомлюсь с SSIS. Создал пакет, в пакете один компонент - скрипт, код на C#. В коде выполняется соединение с удаленным SQL-сервером, выполняется некоторый запрос, перебираются выбранные данные. Далее эти данные записываются в csv и сохраняются в файловой системе локального сервера. Код скрипта примерно такой:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] emptyBytes = new byte[0];

            var exportPath          = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::ExportPath"].Value;
            var connectionString    = (string)Dts.Variables["$Package::LimsConnectionString"].Value;

            var fileFullName = exportPath + "\\export_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss") + ".csv";

            var query = "SELECT [id], [first_name], [middle_name], [last_name], [login] FROM [lims].[Employee]"; //Некоторый запрос, для примера


            Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Запущен процесс выгрузки", 0, emptyBytes);

            var counter = 0;

            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Выполнено подключение к БД", 0, emptyBytes);

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Выполнен запрос к БД", 0, emptyBytes);

                        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileFullName, false))
                        {
                            Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Запущена запись в файл " + fileFullName, 0, emptyBytes);

                            file.WriteLine("Id;FirstName;MiddleName;LastName;Login");

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                counter++;
                                file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", reader["id"], reader["first_name"], reader["middle_name"], reader["last_name"], reader["login"]));
                            }
                        }

                        Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Завершена запись в файл " + fileFullName, 0, emptyBytes);
                    }
                }
            }

            Dts.Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Выгрузка завершена. Обработано " + counter.ToString() + " строк", 0, emptyBytes);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, DateTime.Now.ToString("[dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss] - ") + "Ошибка", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```

Когда выполняю этот пакет в Visual Studio, на сервере, то все отрабатывает, файлики создаются. Далее размещаю пакет на SSIS, создаю задание на агенте для этого пакета. Служба SSIS и служба агента SQL Server запущены от имени учетной записи администратора. Запускаю пакет непосредственно с SSIS-а или через запуск задания агента. В результате все отрабатывает якобы нормально, в отчете пишет, что все хорошо, ошибок нигде нет. А файлы не создаются, ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Просмотри логи операционной системы. Скорее всего там есть какая-то ошибка. Если нет - то тебе нужно создать доп.логирование и понять в каком именно месте оно вылетает без ошибки.

Comment: Пока единственное что удалось найти это информационное сообщение: "Не удается найти описание для идентификатора события 12289 из источника SQLISPackage140. Вызывающий данное событие компонент не установлен на этом локальном компьютере или поврежден. Установите или восстановите компонент на локальном компьютере." Но непонятно о каком компоненте идет речь и куда копать дальше.

Comment: 12289  у SQLISPackage -- это Success. Можешь игнорировать это сообщение. логируйся на каждом чихе и проверяй логи. Так же можешь попробовать отдебажить релизный билд подключив к нему вижуалку в дебаг моде.

Comment: Вообщем, не нашел я причину проблемы. Сделал пакет стандартными средствами SSIS, через компонент задача потока данных. На сервере работает. Если вдруг потребуется выгрузка в какую-нибудь более сложную структуру, например xml, вернусь к данному вопросу.